# no result with these nested loops

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop

I'm trying to nest two while loops and an if-statement.

```
$Query = "SELECT * from lijst";  
$Query2 = "SELECT * from users";
$Result = mysql_query( $Query );  
$Result2 = mysql_query( $Query2 ); 

$Return = "<lijst>"; 
while ( $Lijst = mysql_fetch_object( $Result ))  
{ 

    $Return .= "<lijst>"; 
    while ($Users = mysql_fetch_object( $Result2 ))     
    { 
        if($Lijst['userid'] == $Users['userid'])
        {             
                        $Return .= "<username>".$Users->username."</username>"; 
        }

    }   
    $Return .= "<lijstid>".$Lijst->lijstid."</lijstid>"; 
    $Return .= "</lijst>";  
} 
$Return .= "</lijst>"; 

mysql_free_result($Result); 
mysql_free_result($Result2); 
print ($Return)
```

However, I get no results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check to see if you're getting results from the queries, and if the loops are running.

Comment: Checked! Both queries and loops run :)

Comment: You should really use a join in your query, instead of looping through two resultsets. This is resource-intensive as hell. Try adding more then 100 rows in each table and refresh page to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling `mysql_fetch_object()` you should access your data as object not array

```
 if($Lijst['userid'] == $Users['userid'])
```

should become:

```
 if($Lijst->userid == $Users->userid)
```

Comment: Thanks! It does something now...
It gives all of the results from the lijst-loop. But only one result of the nested loop, Username.

Comment: paste your tables structure othervise we can only guess

Comment: My table structure in mysql: 

Lijst: 
- lijstid (PK)
- userid (FK)

users:
- userid (PK)
- username

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos.

```
while ( $Users = mysql_fetch_object( $Result2 ) ) { if($Lijst['userid'] == $Users['userid') {
```

Should be:

```
while ( $Users = mysql_fetch_object( $Result2 ) ) { if($Lijst['userid'] == $Users['userid']) {
```

And

```
print ($return)
```

Misses the semicolumn at the end

```
print ($return);
```

Besides that, your code seems a bit messy.
The following doesn't do anything:

```
$Return .= "";
```

The following is the same code, but without the mess (and capitals in the variable names). This makes it easier to code and for people to help you.

```
$query   = "SELECT * from lijst";
$query2  = "SELECT * from users";

$result  = mysql_query($query);
$result2 = mysql_query($query2);
$return  = "";

while ($lijst = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    while ($users = mysql_fetch_object($result2)) {
        if ($lijst['userid'] == $users['userid']) {
            $return .= $users->username;
        }
    }
    $return .= "<lijstid>".$lijst->lijstid."</lijstid>"; 
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_free_result($result2);
print ($return);
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed that, but it didn't really seem to help. I changed

`if($Lijst['userid'] == $Users['userid']) `
into
`if($Lijst->userid == $Users->userid)`
And nog I get all of the results from the first loop, but only one of the second, nested loop...